# Laravel Passeport how get user token

Tags: laravel, authentication, token

Helo,
I would like to know how get token by user with laravel passeport ?
I don't want a user to access another user's resource.
I would like to verify that the user's token in the request corresponds to the user's token.

i get the request token with:

```
$token = $request->bearerToken();
```

i don't know how to get user token.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up correctly then passport will keep track of the tokens of each user in each device. However, if you want to retrieve the token of the authenticated user simply use `Auth::user()->token();`

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I tried this method but the token is not the same.

do you know why ?

Comment: ideally I would retrieve a user based on a token if it exists

Comment: $request->bearerToken() simply gives you the token that comes in the header. It's encoded. And Auth::user()->token() gives you the decoded token of that user. So they won't be same.